# .NET Core Console App | Hangfire With Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, hangfire

**Goal:**
Fundamentally I am trying to add a background job, that has dependencies injected, to a console application.

**Problem:**
Although the jobs are queued, they are never executed.

**Program.cs**

```
var appSettings = ConfigHelper.GetConfig();
Console.WriteLine("Initialising Hangfire Server...");
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(appSettings.ConnectionString);
using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started.");

    var t = serviceProvider.GetService<ITestService>();
    t.Test();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**ServiceProviderFactory.cs**

```
public static void Setup()
{
     IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

     ...
        
     services.AddDbContext<Db>(x => x.UseSqlServer(appSettings.ConnectionString));
     services.AddTransient<IInsertLogJob, InsertLogJob>();
     services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();

     _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();  
 }
```

**TestService.cs**

```
public interface ITestService
{
    void Test();
}
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestService> _logger;

    public TestService(ILogger<TestService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void Test()
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Test");
        _logger.LogError("Error");
    }
}
```

**Logger.cs**

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    ...
   Log log = new Log()
            {
                Message = message,
                EventId = eventId.Id,
                ObjectId = eventId.Name,
                LogLevel = logLevel.ToString(),
                CreatedTime = DateTime.Now
            };

   BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IInsertLogJob>(j => j.Insert(log));
}
```

**InsertLogJob.cs**

```
public interface IInsertLogJob
{
    void Insert(Log log);
}

public class InsertLogJob : IInsertLogJob
{
    private Db _dataContext;
    public InsertLogJob(Db context)
    {
        _dataContext = context;
    }
    public void Insert(Log log)//<-- this never happens
    {
        _dataContext.Logs.Add(log);
        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**DB Record**
[image: Screnshot]

So all the code up to the point where the data has to be inserted into the database runs, the Hangfire job gets inserted as per the picture above, but the code is never executed.

Comment: Another way to get visibility is to create a web app and host the hangfire dashboard but not the service. It will show you what your console service is doing. I am facing the exact same challenge you describe. The first problem it will reveal is Hangfire can't find the assembly (unless you define the job class in the console app). Fix that by adding a `runtimeconfig.template.json` per http://www.stempowski.net/net-core/loading-assemblies-in-net-core/ and then you'll be in the same place as me.

Comment: If you use `AddHangfire()` and then `AddHangfireServer()` instead of create a new `BackgroundJobServer` it should just work ... at least that's what happens in asp.net core land. `AddHangfire()` does clever stuff with JobActivator such that you can just schedule background methods and Hangfire will use DI to create the necessary dependencies for your object. (https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)